# Displaying Toast Messages to Inform Success or Failure After Performing a Task in Android-Kotlin-Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a question regarding Android-Kotlin-Jetpack Compose. I have the following code that allows me to modify the geographical coordinates of a retail entity. Here's the code that triggers the modification from the UI:

```kotlin
Row(
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth()
) {
    val openDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    if (openDialog.value) {
        CustomDialog(
            title = "GPS Coordinates",
            message = "Do you want to update the GPS coordinates?",
            onCancel = { openDialog.value = false },
            onValidate = {
                openDialog.value = false
                updateGpsCoordinate()
            },
            cancelText = stringResource(id = R.string.no),
            validateText = stringResource(id = R.string.yes)
        )
    }
}
```

Then, I have a method in the ViewModel to perform the modification by first retrieving the GPS coordinates. Here it is:

```kotlin
fun updateGpsCoordinate() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            val coordinate = locationTrackerRepository.getCurrentLocation()
                ?: throw Exception("Coordinate is null")

            pos.copy(
                lat = coordinate.latitude.toString(),
                lng = coordinate.longitude.toString()
            )

            Log.d("LocationTracker", coordinate.toString())
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("LocationTracker", e.message.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to display a Toast message to inform the user about the success or failure of the modification. How can I retrieve the modification state on the UI to display the Toast? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you need to know about the `SharedFlow` which can be applied here to show toast.

**Brief of SharedFlow**

`SharedFlow` is a hot flow that emits values to all consumers that collect from it. SharedFlow can be used for **one-time events(Show Toast, Snackbar, Broadcast Event, etc)**.

Here is an example of showing `Toast` using `SharedFlow`

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _showToast = MutableSharedFlow<Boolean>()
    val showToastMessage = _showToast.asSharedFlow()

    fun fetchLocation() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            //fetch your location, once fetched emit events
            delay(5000)
            _showToast.emit(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Whatever you emit the value from ViewModel you need to Collect it to show Toast Message.

As you know SharedFlow is a one-time event so you need to observe it using the LaunchedEffect side-effect in Composable Screen.

**Usage**

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen(viewModel: MainViewModel) {

    val context = LocalContext.current

    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        viewModel.showToastMessage.collect { show ->
            if(show) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Location Fetched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the answer I was hoping for, and it has successfully resolved my issue.

Comment: but as LaunchedEffect(true) gets called once, it gets called before even the request is finished, so it doesn't show any toast(in my case).